# How to create training and test DataSetIterators in deeplearning4j?

Tags: deeplearning4j

I am building a recurrent neural network with deeplearning4j and I need to create the training and test data sets.

All the examples provided in [the documentation](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-nn-recurrent) and the [example code](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/seqclassification/UCISequenceClassificationExample.java), use a `CSVSequenceRecordReader` to read CSV files.

Then a `DataSetIterator` is created with the `SequenceRecordReaderDataSetIterator` constructor and fed into the `MultiLayerNetwork.fit()` or the `MultiLayerNetwork.evaluate()` method (depending if it's a training or test data set iterator).

However, in my case, the data set I have is not stored in a CSV file. I access it online through a third-party library, pre-process it to obtain a `List<Data>` and a `List<Labels>` objects.

How can I:

1) create the `DataSetIterator` from my two lists?

2) split the `DataSetIterator` in a training set and a test set?

**Edit**:

I think my question is too broad. Let me try to narrow it down.

I have started to read [this article](https://progur.com/2017/06/how-to-create-lstm-rnn-deeplearning4j.html) which uses a very simple approach to create a data set:

It creates two INDArrays and builds a DataSet from them using the `DataSet(INDArray first, INDArray second)` constructor.

Training the data works using `network.fit(dataSet);`, but I can't evaluate it while training, as the method `evaluate` requires an data set iterator, not a data set.

Moreover, from what I understand, using this approach also means that there is only one huge data set, no mini batches.

I also guess that I could create mini batches from this big data set by using the   `batchBy(int num)` method. But this method returns a list of data sets, and not an data set iterator... iterateWithMiniBatches() does return a data set iterator but when I looked at the source file, it returns null and is deprecated. Then I tried to see if there is an implementation of the DataSetIterator I could use, but there are a lot of them. I tried the BaseDataSetIterator but it does not take a DataSet as constructor parameter but a DataSetFetcher... Yet another layer.

Is there somewhere an example that shows how to create a data set without using the default record readers? Or should I just create my how implementation of a record reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

`MultiLayerNetwork.evaluate()` accepts `ListDataSetIterator` as a parameter

If you have a `List<Data> object` you can first map it into a `double[] featureVector` and a `double[] labelVector` and then create a `ListDataSetIterator` like this

```
    INDArray x = Nd4j.create(featureVector, new int[]{featureVector.length/numberOfFeatures, numberOfFeatures}, 'c');
    INDArray y = Nd4j.create(labelVector, new int[]{labelVector.length/numberOfLabels, numberOfLabels}, 'c');

    final DataSet allData = new DataSet(x,y);

    final List<DataSet> list = allData.asList();

    ListDataSetIterator iterator = new ListDataSetIterator(list);
```

For 2) you should just create two seperate iterators, one for training, one for testing.

You can then evaluate your net with `net.evaluate(testIterator);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a precision though about `allData.asList()`. According to the API doc, this takes each example of the DataSet and creates a list of DataSets containing one example each (i.e. a minibatch of size one). If I want to create batches of size n, I should better use `batchBy(n)`